# UWP - How to get device model

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, mobile-devices

I need to know my device model when my app running.

I try many ways to get that like:

```
string[] properties = { "System.Devices.ModelName"}; await PnpObject.FindAllAsync(PnpObjectType.DeviceContainer, properties);
```

or `new EasClientDeviceInformation().SystemProductName;`

But both never return my device model, like `Lumia 640`. On desktop it works fine but on mobile not.

Any ideas to solve my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Lumia Models are not the actual Model Names. For example my `Lumia 640` is `RM-1073`. But one of my friend who uses a Carrier Locked `Lumia 640` phone model is `RM-1072`.

You can get this info using

```
var clientDeviceInformation = new EasClientDeviceInformation();
string systemProductName = clientDeviceInformation.SystemProductName;
```

There is a way to receive Lumia Model Number too. If the phone's Name is never changed, it will still have the original Name. You can retrieve that using

```
string friendlyName = clientDeviceInformation.FriendlyName;
```

However there might be very few people who does not change their phone's name.